# Create React App unit tests does not execute in VMWare Horizon Client

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

When I create a react application using create-react-app in VMWare Horizon Client(VDI) Windows Machine, it runs and works fine but the while executing `npm run test` it gives me following exception

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1372:28)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (Z:\Workplace\abc\abc-UI\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:159:10)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1378:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abc-ui@0.1.0 test: `react-scripts test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the abc-ui@0.1.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-30T10_53_14_533Z-debug.log
```

I did same create react app on my regular windows machine and executed `npm run test` and it executes successfully as expected.

I've tried removing and reinstalling node_modules, also enabled polling, but of no use.

Also `npm run test` in `package.json` uses react-scripts to run test I've not made any changes to the scripts in `package.json`

Node and npm versions on both my local machine and VDI are same

```
Node version : 10.4.1
npm : 6.1.0
```

I've same version of Windows as well and same version of create-react-app is being used. This issue seems to persist only in VDI environment. Also I can not upgrade or downgrade npm/Node versions on my VDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this error only occurs if we execute this code in shared network drive. If we run same code from a localdisk that is disk storage such as C drive the test cases execute as expected.